# How to configure "search.max_open_scroll_context" on AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm using aws Elasticsearch (version: 7.1) and I want to config search.max_open_scroll_context to bigger.
my es doesn't have any auth, and another request like /_cluster/state is ok.  But when I do this I got this:

```
curl -X PUT xx.xx.com/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
    "persistent" : {
        "search.max_open_scroll_context": 5000
    },
    "transient": {
        "search.max_open_scroll_context": 5000
    }
}
'
{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}
```

I see their doc says that their es 7.1 only support these: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html

```
/_cluster/settings for several properties4:

action.auto_create_index

action.search.shard_count.limit

indices.breaker.fielddata.limit

indices.breaker.request.limit

indices.breaker.total.limit

cluster.max_shards_per_node

cluster.blocks.read_only
```

but I didn't find search.max_open_scroll_context, How to configure "search.max_open_scroll_context" on AWS Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reach out to AWS Support Team for this. Just let them know the value of "search.max_open_scroll_context" that you are looking for and they will update it from the backend.

Answer (score -3):

```
 PUT _cluster/settings

  {
      "persistent" : {
           "action.search.shard_count.limit" : "3500"
      }
  }
```

works fine. 
I think the error was in missing quotes